# c++ custom iterator for matrix class

Tags: c++, stl

I have a Matrix class and now I want to write an iterator for it.
My class looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
vector<vector<T>> data;
Matrix(const vector<vector<T>>& d)
        : data(d) {
}
std::pair<size_t, size_t> size() const {
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> s;
    s.first = data.size();
    s.second = data[0].size();
    return s;
}
```

And I want to write an iterator for it. But how can I do that? I found following code:

```
class iterator
    {
        public:
            typedef iterator self_type;
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef T& reference;
            typedef T* pointer;
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef int difference_type;
            iterator(pointer ptr) : ptr_(ptr) { }
            self_type operator++() { self_type i = *this; ptr_++; return i; }
            self_type operator++(int junk) { ptr_++; return *this; }
            reference operator*() { return *ptr_; }
            pointer operator->() { return ptr_; }
            bool operator==(const self_type& rhs) { return ptr_ == rhs.ptr_; }
            bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) { return ptr_ != rhs.ptr_; }
        private:
            pointer ptr_;
    };

 iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(data_);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(data_ + size_);
    }
```

How can I make it work together?
I want to iterate every element in matrix

Comment: I strongly suggest you store the actual matrix data in a single dimensional vector instead of a 2d vector.  A 2d vector has no cache coherency for the rows.  It also allows you to use the stock iterator.

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea

Comment: That iterator code doesn't looks broken. For example, it has the pre-increment operator doing post-increment and vice versa. The pre-increment should normally return by reference as well.

Comment: what do you want to iterate? rows? columns? elements (in what order, column-wise or row-wise?)

Answer (score 0):

Here the C++ solution without boost. I also provide a complete and tested source code example.

The source code is compiled and tested with MS Visual Studio 19.

First hint: I would always use `std::valarray` for matrix calculations. Please read about it.

Explantion to this solution:

We will used a vector of vector of int to represent the matrix.
Rows can be easily accessed. They are the first dimension of the data matrix. If we want a iterator for a row, we simple return the standard iterator for a vector. With that, we will immediately have full functionality. Simple.

Unfortunately columns are different. They are slices in the contiguous memory of the data. So, what we will implement as a solution is: Create a vector for each column with references to the data in the correct position.

That sounds more easy than it is, because we cannot store references in containers in C++. So, either to use `std::reference_wrapper` or build our own reference wrapper. I had issues with assigning values to dereferenced `std::reference_wrapper` and build an own one. A assignment operator has been added.

With that, we can return an iterator to columns, based on the reference vectors.

Many additional functions can be added. Of course you can replace the int with any other value or templatize it.

I put some test code in main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>


// Unfortunately the std::reference_wrapper does not work as expected.
// So we will build our own one
class IntRef
{
    // Here we will store the reference
    std::tuple<int&> t;
public:
    // Constructor. Take reference and store it in tuple
    IntRef(int&& intV) : t(intV) {}     

    // Assignment to the referenced value
    int operator =(const int i) { std::get<0>(t) = i; return i; }      

    // Explicit type cast to int&
    operator int& () { return std::get<0>(t); }                        

    // And, return the reference
    decltype(&std::get<0>(t)) operator&() { return &std::get<0>(t); }  
};


// Some definitions to make reading easier
using IntRefV = std::vector<IntRef>;
using MatrixCIterator = std::vector<IntRef>::iterator;
using Columns = std::vector<int>;
using MatrixRIterator = Columns::iterator;


// The matrix
class Matrix
{
public:
    // Constructor defines the matrix size
    Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns);

    // Iterators for rows are simple, becuase we have vectors of columns. Use unterlying iterator
    MatrixRIterator rowIterBegin(size_t row) { return data[row].begin(); }
    MatrixRIterator rowIterEnd(size_t row) { return data[row].end(); }  

    // Column iterator is complicated. Retzurn iterator to vevtor of references to column values
    MatrixCIterator columnIterBegin(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].begin(); }
    MatrixCIterator columnIterEnd(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].end(); }

    // Access data of matrix
    std::vector<int>& operator [] (const size_t row) { return data[row]; }

    // And, for debug purposes. Output all data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Matrix& m) {
        std::for_each(m.data.begin(), m.data.end(), [&os](const Columns& columns) {std::copy(columns.begin(), columns.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });
        return os;
    }
protected:
    //The matrix, vector of vector of int
    std::vector<Columns> data; 

    // The references to columns in data
    std::vector<IntRefV> columnReferences{};    
};

// Constructor. Build basic matrix and then store references to columns in data 
Matrix::Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns) : data(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns)), columnReferences(numberOfColumns)
{
    for (size_t column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; ++column) 
        for (size_t row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
            columnReferences[column].emplace_back(IntRef(std::move(data[row][column]))); // Std::move creates a rvalue reference (needed for constructor, nothing will be moved)
}



// Some test data for the istream_iterator
std::istringstream testData("1 2 10");



// Test the matrix
int main()
{
    // Define a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns
    Matrix matrix(3, 4);
    // Test 1: Fill all values in column 2 with 42
    for (MatrixCIterator ci = matrix.columnIterBegin(2); ci != matrix.columnIterEnd(2); ++ci) {
        *ci = 42;
    }
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 2 filled with 42\n\n";

    // Test 2: Read input from istream and copy put that in column 1
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(testData), 3, matrix.columnIterBegin(1));
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 1 filled with testData '"<< testData.str() << "'\n\n";

    // Test 3: Copy column 2 to cout (Print column 2)
    std::copy(matrix.columnIterBegin(2), matrix.columnIterEnd(2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "This is column 2\n\n";

    // Test 4: Sum up the first 2 values of column 1 and show result
    std::cout << "\nSum of first 2 values of column 1:  " << std::accumulate(matrix.columnIterBegin(1), matrix.columnIterBegin(1)+2, 0) << "\n\n";

    // Test 5: Fill all values in row 0 with 33
    std::for_each(matrix.rowIterBegin(0), matrix.rowIterEnd(0), [](int& i) { i = 33; });
    std::cout << matrix << "Row 0 filled with 33\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that this gives you an idea on how it could work . . .